# Is current "Avadhoot Dattatreya Guru Gaddi tradition" the "MISSING IN SIGHT" Hinduism that is continuing from Harappan Avadhoot of 3500 BCE?

Tags: tantra, dattatreya

Three faced **HARAPPAN AVADHOOT** sitting in SIDDHA Asan (not lotus pose) having three in one headgear. This persona is there in all major urban sites of Harappa and even found at SANAULI coffin.
The **HARAPPAN AVADHOOT** is mentioned in DHOLAVIRA BOARD; Harappa; Mohenjo-Daro; Mehargarh;Banawali objects.

The Datt tradition is a **seat or Gaddi or position** tradition which is represented not by a single person. The designated person as Datt changes from time to time and may be at same time the POSITION or SEAT is offered to more than one person or **ROYAL AVADHOOT** (KING PRIEST).

**EARLY HARAPPAN DATT TRADITION** before 8000 BCE to 3000 BCE
This is when the Rig Veda (6000 BCE) and related Ramayana (5000 BCE) personas were connected to DATT tradition. Inn history we very well know that King Yadu was a disciple of Datt seat tradition (see Avadhoot Gita; Rig Ved that mentions King Yadu as son of King Yayati).

**MATURE HARAPPAN DATT TRADITION** 3000 BCE to 2000 BCE
The Harappan seals show three faced **HARAPPAN AVADHOOT** sitting in SIDDHA Asan (not lotus pose) having three in one headgear. This persona is there in all major urban sites as well as  **HARAPPAN AVADHOOT** is mentioned in DHOLAVIRA BOARD; Harappa; Mohenjo-Daro; Mehargarh ; Banawali objects.

**LATE HARAPPAN AVADHOOT DATT TRADITION**
many artifacts' inscriptions reveal Dattatreya tradition without any motifs as revealed by research of DR GUPTA HARAPPAN CODE 2021.

**POST HARAPPAN (PRE-MODERN INDIA) DATT AVADHOOT TRADITION**
After the drying up of SARASWATI RIVER in 2000 BCE to 1000 BCE when the Mahabharata (1000 BCE) happened; the tradition continued and AVADHOOT tradition is mentioned in Mahabharata.

**MODERN INDIA & NEPAL WITH TRADTION OF DATT AVADHOOT**
MAHA-ANUBHAV PANTH;
JAI KRISHNI PANTH;
DATTATREYA SAMPRADYA;
NATH PANTH;
MACCHANDER NATH PANTH;
GORAKSH NATH PANTH.

Comment: Please clarify the question, you have added a lot of detail, but the question is not clear. Please make that clear, of what you are trying to ask here.